# createjs fixed/floating hallo editor

Tags: frontend, editing, createjs, hallo-js

I am trying to achieve the same effect that is seen in [this](https://github.com/bergie/hallo/blob/master/examples/fixed.html) example of the hallo editor, and here is a screenshot:

[image]

Basically I would rather have the editor appear above the current content that is being edited than at the top of the page. Is this something that can be achieved by passing settings to `midgardeCreate()`?

I thought something along these lines would get me on the right track, but this keeps the editor at the top of the page.

```
jQuery('body').midgardCreate('configureEditor', 'default', 'halloWidget', {
  plugins: {
    halloformat: {},
    halloblacklist: {
      tags: ['br']
    }
  },
  toolbarState: 'halloToolbarFixed',
  parentElement: '.create-ui-toolbar-dynamictoolarea .create-ui-tool-freearea'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with midgard, but I have used hallo. I think the only change you need to make is here:

```
toolbarState: 'halloToolbarFixed',
```

to:

```
toolbar: 'halloToolbarFixed',
```